# WCSession connection fails at specific moment

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

I have a weird behavior happening to me while using the watch connectivity.

I start the session from the AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

The user's goes through the login process, and when the user get's to the home screen if the user open's the Watch it seems that something goes wrong with the session.
At this point I get this log:

```
[WC] -[WCSession onqueue_handleDictionaryMessageRequest:withPairingID:]_block_invoke delegate MCEWatchSessionDelegate does not implement delegate method
[WC] -[WCSession _onqueue_sendResponseError:identifier:dictionaryMessage:] identifier: [identifier] with WCErrorCodeDeliveryFailed
```

And at this moment if I print the error on the watch if get:

```
Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7014 "Payload could not be delivered." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Payload could not be delivered.}
```

and there is nothing in the login process using the session or anything related to the WatchConnectivity.

If the user opens the watch app on the login screen, everything works as expected.
If I close and open the app again (session get's activated again) it runs normally and the issue is gone.
If I activate the session again from the iPhone app after the watch has tried and failed to send the message, it goes back to normal.
If I dispatch a queue with a delay, activating the session again on the Iphone app to after the home screen is shown, it also work's normally.

The problem seems to happen only on the first time the user enters the application after the installation, manually log's in and get's to the home screen.